# Loading Data on a UITableViewCell with Custom Xib

Tags: ios, ios4, uitableview, properties

I created a custom cell with IB

In my interface, I have 3 UILabels and an UIImageView.

I wired all the outlets and then back in my controller, I have the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    static NSString* MyIndenifier = @"MyCell";
PersonCell* cell = (PersonCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIndenifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PersonCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (PersonCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [[mutablePeopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getContactName];
}

return cell;
```

In my PersonCell.h I have the following in the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface PersonCell : UITableViewCell {
IBOutlet    UILabel*        nameLabel;
IBOutlet    UIImageView*    thumbnailImage;
IBOutlet    UILabel*        addressLabelStreet;
IBOutlet    UILabel*        addressLabelCityAndStateWithZip;
}

- (void)setNameLabel:(NSString *)paramNameText;
- (void)setThumbnailImage:(UIImage *)paramImage;
- (void)setAddressLabel:(NSString *)paramAddress;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* addressLabelStreet;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* addressLabelCityAndStateWithZip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* thumbnailImage;

@end
```

}

I get the following errors

PersonCell.h:28: error: setter '-thumbnailImage' argument type does not match property type
PersonCell.h:28: error: setter '-nameLabel' argument type does not match property type
PersonCell.h:28: error: setter '-addressLabelStreet' argument type does not match property type
PersonCell.h:28: error: setter '-addressLabelCityAndStateWithZip' argument type does not match property type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you defined the setters so you can't use the properties / synthesize.

If you're doing something custom with the setters then create a new method name like

- (void) MyCustomNameForHandlingAddresses

Answer (score 1):

You already used property for gettter and setter so why use custom set method just use :
      nameLabel.text=@"Some text"
in implementation where you need.